# React addons update - how to insert an object into an array of objects?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects represented by `this.state.blocks` . How do I insert a new object into this array at position `pos`? This is what i have so far, but I am getting the error

> Error: update(): expected target of $push to be an array; got [object
>   Object].

```
let newBlocks = update(this.state, {
    blocks: {
        [pos] : {$push: [obj]}
    }
});
this.setState({
    blocks: newBlocks
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$push` appends element(s) to the end of the array and you need [`$splice`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html#available-commands) here:

```
this.setState({
  blocks: update(this.state.blocks, {$splice: [[pos, 0, obj]]})
})
```

will insert `obj` into `this.state.blocks` at index specified by `pos` (deleting 0 items first).`splice` works according to the spec:

> **startIndex:**
>   index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0).
>   **If greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be
>   set to the length of the array**. If negative, will begin that many
>   elements from the end.

so it will work fine as long as the `startIndex` is within the length of the array